# Docker image build failed on Mac M1 chip

Tags: java, docker, maven

I'm trying to build a simple docker image, inside a maven project, adding the image build as part of the maven build process:

```
<build>
        <finalName>my-api</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Docker -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                            <!-- <goal>push</goal> -->
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <repository>reponame/${project.name}</repository>
                    <tag>${project.version}</tag>
                    <skipDockerInfo>true</skipDockerInfo>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>
```

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
EXPOSE 8080
ADD target/*.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java -jar /app.jar" ]
```

But it fails, always get the same error trace, no matter which image I use, the error persists.

Error:

> Caused by:
> com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException:
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: could not load FFI provider
> jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.Provider
>
> Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
> /private/var/folders/hz/rgppp8250rsdp86kf_tfjvqw0000gp/T/jffi8502916075702391528.dylib:
> dlopen(/private/var/folders/hz/rgppp8250rsdp86kf_tfjvqw0000gp/T/jffi8502916075702391528.dylib,
> 0x0001): tried:
> '/private/var/folders/hz/rgppp8250rsdp86kf_tfjvqw0000gp/T/jffi8502916075702391528.dylib'
> (fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'i386,x86_64',
> need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/jffi8502916075702391528.dylib' (no such
> file)

Other images I tried:

- openjdk:13-alpine3.9
- openjdk:8-jre-alpine3.9
- azul/zulu-openjdk-alpine:17.0.2-17.32.13-arm64

**My java version**: openjdk version "11.0.13" 2021-10-19 LTS

**My Docker version**: Docker version 20.10.11, build dea9396

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the Spotify docker client showing in the logs? Are you using some kind of Maven/Gradle plugin? What happens if you build using `docker build` command?

Comment: I'm using the dockerfile-maven-plugin and including the image build as part of the mvn execution, running the docker build command works.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like the `dockerfile-maven-plugin` uses a runtime based on x86 architecture and won't run on Apple M1 (Arm).
The plugin is now inactive so you should try something else, for example the [fabric8-maven-plugin](https://maven.fabric8.io/)

```
          <plugin>
            <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.38.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>build</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8):

Both of the spotify docker maven plugins are no longer maintained. They need to upgrade their dependency to a version that supports aarch64.

In our case there was significant refactoring needed to move to fabric8's plugin or to use maven exec so we wanted to continue to use spotify plugin.

Fortunately, you can force the plugin to use a particular dependency by adding a `<dependencies>` section to your plugin section.

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4.6</version>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>com.github.jnr</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jnr-unixsocket</artifactId>
                            <version>0.38.14</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
```

Comment: Apologies for continually editing this response... This works using the above versions (THANK YOU). I tried updating to the most recent version of the plugin (1.4.13) which gave me an error, but using 1.4.6 worked fine on my M1 Macbook (as it worked prior on my intel Mac).

Comment: Thanks! I can confirm that this workaround works with `1.4.6`, and has some issue with `1.4.13`.

Comment: Yeah if you use 1.4.13 you get `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: invalid type: ssize_t
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.jnr.ffi.provider.BadType.getNativeType (BadType.java:43)` for some reason

Comment: Any other versions that work between 1.4.6 and 1.4.13?

Answer (score 4):

I met the same problem.According to the error message, it should be a connection error with the docker daemon.It seems that the plugin won't support Arm socket and you can do this:

(1) install socat

```
brew install socat
```

(2) set port forwarding

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:2375,range=127.0.0.1/32,reuseaddr,fork UNIX-CLIENT:/var/run/docker.sock
```

(3) set environment variable

```
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://127.0.0.1:2375
```